# Как добавить/получить ряд в Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

Не могу разобраться как добавить новый ряд в таблицу sql.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        testLinqDataContext db = new testLinqDataContext();
        IEnumerable<customer> data = from customer in db.customers select customer; // выбор всего из таблицы клиентов

        dataGridView1.DataSource = data; // покажи в гриде

        string name = textBox1.Text;
        string lastname = textBox2.Text;
        if(name != null && lastname != null)
        {
          //занести в бд
        }

    }
```

Comment: Чтобы понять хоть что-то покажите потроха `testLinqDataContext`

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, что код должен выглядеть где-то так:

```
 if(name != null && lastname != null)
    {
      customer newCustomer = new Customer();
      //не знаю как поля называются в Вашем классе, 
      //но я думаю, что Вы поймете суть
      newCustomer.name = name;
      newCustomer.lastname = lastname;
      ...
      db.customers.Add(newCustomer);
      db.SubmitChanges();

    }
```